# Configure psqlodbc-10.03.0 on AIX 7.1

Tags: postgresql, odbc, aix, unixodbc

during configuring psqlodbc-10.03.0 on AIX 7.1 using the follwing command:

./configure  --with-libpq=/app/postgresql10ff/lib/ --with-unixodbc=/usr/local/bin/odbc_config

i receive the below error:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... config/install-sh -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking -Wall is a valid compile option... yes
configure: using /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib
checking last argument to SQLColAttribute is SQLLEN *... yes
checking for pg_config... /app/postgresql10ff/bin/pg_config
checking for prove... prove
checking build system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.4.0
checking host system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.4.0
checking how to print strings... print -r
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... no
checking how to convert powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.4.0 file names to powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.4.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.4.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... print -r --
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC...  -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag  -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... aix7.1.4.0 ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... no
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for library containing SQLGetPrivateProfileString... -lodbcinst
checking for pthread_create in -lpthreads... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode in -lpq... no
configure: error: libpq library version >= 9.2 is required
```

although i have postgres VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.1 and the output of pg_config:

```
BINDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/bin
DOCDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/share/doc
HTMLDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/share/doc
INCLUDEDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /app/postgresql10ff/include/server
LIBDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/lib
LOCALEDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/share/locale
MANDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/share/man
SHAREDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/share
SYSCONFDIR = /app/postgresql10ff/etc
PGXS = /app/postgresql10ff/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--with-includes=/opt/freeware/include:/usr/include' '--with-libraries=/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib64' '--prefix=/app/postgresql10ff' 'CFLAGS=-maix64' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-bbigtoc,-lm'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -DFRONTEND -I/opt/freeware/include -I/usr/include
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -maix64
CFLAGS_SL =
LDFLAGS = -L../../src/common -Wl,-bbigtoc,-lm -L/opt/freeware/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-blibpath:'/app/postgresql10ff/lib:/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/lib'
LDFLAGS_EX =
LDFLAGS_SL =  -Wl,-bnoentry -Wl,-H512 -Wl,-bM:SRE
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lz -lreadline -lld -lm  -lpthreads
VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.1
```

and output of the following  command ls -l /app/postgresql10ff/lib/libpq*

```
-rw-r--r--    1 postgres dba          619751 Apr 11 18:51 /app/postgresql10ff/lib/libpq.a

-rwxr-xr-x    1 postgres dba          104167 Apr 11 18:51 /app/postgresql10ff/lib/libpqwalreceiver.so
```

appreciate your support to fix this error.

Comment: What does this command say: `ls -l /app/postgresql10ff/lib/libpq*`

Comment: and please edit your Q to show that `ls -l` output, please don't try to cram it into a comment ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: hi Lorinczy/shelter, Q updated with the output of the ls -l

Comment: Ok, now try this: `nm -g -x -X32_64 /app/postgresql10ff/lib/libpq.a | grep PQsetSingleRowMode`

Comment: hi, the output:
.PQsetSingleRowMode  T  0x10008cec
PQsetSingleRowMode   D  0x200038e0

Comment: @saad So your library does have such `PQsetSingleRowMode` function. Let's hope it is of 64-bit. Maybe you forgot to pass to `configure` option `-maix64` in `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond as you can see in the output of pg_config:
CONFIGURE = '--with-includes=/opt/freeware/include:/usr/include' '--with-libraries=/opt/freeware/lib64:/usr/lib64' '--prefix=/app/postgresql10ff' 'CFLAGS=-maix64' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-bbigtoc,-lm'
do i need to declare it in another variable ?

Comment: I'd say `LDFLAGS="-maix64 -Wl,-bbigtoc -lm"`

Comment: Any follow up on this @saad?